# Typescript supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a function like this:

```
function foo(a, b, c, d, e) {
    // something creative
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

It works fine.

...But when I call it like this:

```
const lastTwo = [4, 5];
foo(1, 2, 3, ...lastTwo);
```

Typescript screams that:

**`error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`**

How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the [apply function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), but you'll also need to have all the params in the array:

```
const args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
foo.apply(null, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your method signature has a a specific number of arguments, yet you  are calling it with a variable number of arguments. You can solve this by changing the signature.

```
function foo(a, b, c, ...remaining) {
    // something creative
}

const lastTwo = [4, 5];
foo(1, 2, 3, ...lastTwo);
```